# Web service instance for each core in 6 core processor PC

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a windows web service written in C# and would like to know, if I have a PC with 6 core processor, is it possible to run 1 instance of my web service for each core?

If yes, then how?

Comment: Self-hosted or hosted in IIS?

Comment: In Windows OS in IIS. But I also might run it in Linux OS with mono.

Comment: You can set an application domain to have more than one process in IIS. You can also set it to use processor affinity if the reason you want this is you hit some bug when moving across processors. Generally this only improves things if the code you are running has either a thread safety bug or a bug that causes it to crash entirely (so at least other requests are being processed by the other instances until it spins up again) which one is better off fixing. The server site might be a better place for a question like this; stack overflow is more for programming questions.